# Why does adding an empty fragment fix React.memo rerendering?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that's something like:

```
return (
  <div>
    {isFoo ? <Foo /> : null}
    {arr.map(val => <Bar key={val} />)}
  </div>
);
```

I added `React.memo` to `Bar` and the props don't change, but `Bar` rerenders every time this component rerenders. React Profiler says "This is the first time the component is rendered."

However, if I wrap the array in an empty fragment, it stops rerendering unnecessarily:

```
return (
  <div>
    {isFoo ? <Foo /> : null}
    <>
      {arr.map(val => <Bar key={val} />)}
    </>
  </div>
);
```

Why does this happen? Is this expected React behavior or is it a bug? I'm assuming it has to do with the conditional `<Foo />`.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue you describe, but in my test the first example you give does not render `Bar` when the parent renders. See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-elgamal-q6vf8b?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Hmm might've been a specific version of React, I can't repro anymore either. Thought my old question was interesting so started a bounty

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the expected behavior of React because when you have an array of components as a child of a parent component, React has to make sure that the order and the identity of each child component haven't changed.

In this case, if the parent component is rerendered React cannot be certain that the order and the identity of the child components haven't changed so it will rerender them.

But if you wrap the array with an empty fragment, that will be the new parent for the array and now React can be certain that the order and the identity of the child components haven't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the array in an empty fragment.

```js
return (
  <div>
    {isFoo ? <Foo /> : null}
    <>
      {arr.map(val => <Bar key={val} />)}
    </>
  </div>
);
```

In this version of the component, the array is wrapped in an empty fragment `(<> ... </>)` which mitigates the unnecessary component re-render.